# Scala If and For Loops issue

Tags: scala

I have a list that i want to parse its element and subelement and give them as variable for dataframe query
but i get an error can anybody help here is my code

```
val ListParser = ("age,15,20","revenue,1,2")
val vars = "category in (1,2,4)"
val resultQuery : Dataset[Row] =
      if(ListParser.size == 0){

         responses.filter(vars)

      }else if(ListParser.size == 1){

        responses.filter(vars +" AND " + responses(ListParser(0)).between(ListParser(1).toInt, ListParser(2).toInt))

      }else if(ListParser.size >= 2){

        responses.filter(vars + " AND " + {for(a <- ListParser){
          val myInnerList : List[String] = a.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
          responses(myInnerList(0)).between(myInnerList(1).toInt,myInnerList(2).toInt)
        }})


      }else{

        responses.filter(vars)

      }
```

and i have another question i want only the value of response.filter() to be in resultQuery val

Comment: you cannot name the variable `var` - it's a keyword

Comment: Yeah i meant vars i will correct it Thanks

Comment: describe what's the error

Comment: well i have the issue in the case when ListParser.size >= 2 for a in listparser that i added doesn't seem to work

Comment: update the question, after reading this I have no idea what the problem is, what exception is thrown etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing SQL syntax with spark object syntax

try `(listParser.map( s => {val l =s.split(","); s"""${l(0)} between (${l(1)},${l(2)})"""}) :+ vars).mkString(" AND ")` (assuming listParser is indeed a list and not a tuple )

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses it was really helpful, it got rid of the error that i was having but still got an issue it could not read the values in between because they are strings and they need to be number (int, float, timestamp)

Comment: Well actually i just needed to convert those values to the desire one using (.toInt ..... ) and it works. Thank you so much @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz